# Replacing a html tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all `ol` (ordered list) tags with `ul` (unordered list). It works, but when it actually does swap, then a new thing is written and suppose you want to add to the list, it doesn't. Therefore, I think something is wrong with the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ol').replaceWith( "<ul>" + $('ol').html() + "</ul>" );
});
```

Essentially, it's working, but this line isn't letting me add new list object.

Comment: How are you trying to add the new list object(s), can you please show *all* the "*[mcve]*" code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Do you want to replace **every** `ol` tag with `ul`, or just specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.each($('ol'), function(ind) {
  $(this).replaceWith("<ul>" + $(this).html() + "</ul>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy and you don't even have to use jQuery.

```
var ol = document.querySelector('ol');
ol.outerHTML = ol.outerHTML.replace(/ol/, 'ul');
```

In case you want to replace **every** `ol` tag with `ul`, you need to use `querySelectorAll()` and run a loop. example:

```
var ol = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
for(var i = 0; i < ol.length; i++) {
    ol[i].outerHTML = ol[i].outerHTML.replace(/ol/, 'ul');
}
```

[Fiddle 1](http://jsbin.com/xozaguyeta/edit?html,js,output), [Fiddle 2](http://jsbin.com/qakekuxixe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You need `querySelectorAll` for replacing all of them

Comment: @quirimmo True, but the op didn't said anything about all of them. i'll update it anyway

Answer (score 0):

replace operation you are doing on the element which is already created in DOM. if you add new element as a  unordered list then it will come as a  unordered list.so each time you add new element , you have to call replace method to replace as a Ordered list